# hiredis blpop usage

Tags: redis

I am writing a small program. I am using zmq and once a client sends some data, the server which has two threads receives this data in one thread. This thread adds some extra info and has to write to redis. The second thread should be blocked on the redis to receive any updates happening through the first thread. this second thread should get all this data pushed by the first thread.

There is RPUSH and BLPOP operations. I would love to have a cpp client but looks like the one that is there has limited functionality. I am going with the hiredis (officially supported). Can I have some pointers on what are the apis that I need to use to achieve the functionality I require?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: [This might help](https://github.com/antirez/hiredis/)

Comment: I saw that as an official support but question is, if I use the redisCommand with BLPOP, does it block till there is data coming?